# What would cause a printer to print correctly then stop half way through?

Tags: windows, windows-10, printing, printer, network-printer

3 Machines.

1 Machine prints a full 3MB and 300 pages correctly just fine.

The other 2 will print and then half way through they start to print out like this:
[image]

Not sure how to debug this. Not sure what the common issue would be.

Comment: I'd start troubleshooting by investigating the *differences* between the working machine and the non-working machines.  Good things to consider are OS, print driver version, network card/driver version, connected network switch, running programs, source documents being printed, etc.

Comment: How large is the spool file? I have seen many cases where Windows had problems managing large spool files (at least hundreds of MB).

Answer (score -1):

I remember such Issue due to a dirty laser unit (optical sensor). But that wouldnt explain one machine works fine (was it probably coincidence?)